# Forming a connected Island of Xs

Tags: graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, minimum-spanning-tree

Given a 2D array of Os and Xs, find the minimum number of Os that need to be flipped into Xs to connect all the Xs connected. An X is connected to another Xs if they are adjacent to each other(Not diagonally).

Sample input:

A =

```
  [ OOOXOOO

    OOXXOXO

    OXOOOXO ]
```

Output :
2

The idea I had in my mind was choosing an X and then keep on travelling to the nearest X while flipping the Os in between till we connect all the Xs. Is anything wrong with this or can you suggest a better approach?

Also, is this similar to finding the Minimum Spanning tree using Kruskal's Aglo or Prim's Algo?

Comment: I do not have a solution, but I don't think the approach you suggested is correct. Consider for example three isolated Xs. Looking for the shortest possible path between two of these will not necessarily give you an optimal solution. Instead you may have to find a central point between the three Xs, and then use the shortest path from each X to the central point: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EL87v.png This looks to me like a [Steiner tree problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem). The Steiner tree problem generalizes the MST problem, but no efficient algorithm is known.

Comment: After further investigation, it seems your problem directly corresponds to the [Rectilinear Steiner Tree problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectilinear_Steiner_tree), which is NP-hard.